# ¿Cómo obtener datos del dispositivo del cliente?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo una duda en cuestión de un sistema que estoy realizando y es que debo de obtener información del dispositivo en el que están haciendo las peticiones, en este caso si lo hacen desde una computadora o dispositivo movíl.

No sé si se pueda obtener mediante jQuery o JavaScript, y los datos que debería de recuperar son MAC address, nombre de dispositivo, (información de este tipo).

Comment: Si quieres saber si se trata de un dispositivo movil o una computadora puedes recurrir a simplemente el size del dispositivo, para no tener que ponerte a averiguar direcciones IP que por supuesto no te van a dar esta informacion.

Comment: @Riven, si quisiera saber mas sobre la información del dispositivo?, en este caso necesito verificar y saber si es de un equipo en especifico.

Comment: Esa información es potencialmente peligrosa también, podrías tener problemas legales si no le indicas al usuario que se va a usar esa información para un propósito en especifico, pero bueno... fuera de esto hasta el momento no me he puesto a revisar si en javascript puro o en jquery hay alguna forma de obtener la MAC address o almenos la dirección IP de alguien pero si se que se puede saber la direccion IP mediante PHP, pero no se si la MAC.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ese comentario, específicamente es para controlar su ubicación al momento de dar servicio de soporte, y no queremos que vaya a ocupar otro dispositivo o que alguien le haga su trabajo o suplantarlo.

Comment: Pues... debes tener en cuenta muchos factores en esa parte, por ejemplo, que en ese caso el usuario simplemente puede recurrir a una VPN y hacerse pasar por el usuario con la misma dirección IP de este, y pues esto genera el inconveniente de que al usar una VPN la geolocalización también es afectada, por lo que realmente el problema es mas gordo de lo que crees amigo... :C, la única forma legitima de saber la ubicación de esa persona es haber previamente guardado un registro de la verdadera ubicación de esa persona y posteriormente usar algo llamado triangulación para comparar las ubicaciones.

Comment: Al igual si ocupan alguna aplicación para determinar la ubicación del dispositivo haciendose pasar por si estuvieran en el lugar.

Comment: De hecho eso que dijiste es un VPN.